# Как записать информацию в сектор носителя?

Tags: c#

Знаю, что вроде делается через CreateFile, но так и не понял.
Буду благодарен, если ответите как это сделать :)

Answer (score 1):

!?

Единственный разумный вариант - открыть с помощью `CreateFile` у-во `\\.\PhysicalDrive0`, как написано в [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx). Это позволит с минимальными затратами пользовать по физическому содержимому накопителя. Но опять же - не забываем про права. Нужны административные. Или около того.

Comment: Но насколько я знаю, С-sharp использует pinvoke.

Comment: Ну и что?

Comment: Просто прописать CreateFile, он будет орать, что такой функции не существует. Вроде бы там надо грузить библиотеку kernel32, но увы у меня ничего не выходит.

Comment: Правильно, тогда посмотрите примеры использования PInvoke. Для начала более простые. А потом адаптируйте под CreateFile.

Comment: Тогда ещё один вопрос задам :)
Какую директиву using надо подключить, чтобы использовать DllImport?

Comment: Нашёл.)Всё,спасибо за ответ.)